# How to use `setInterval` without `use before define` error?

Tags: eslint, setinterval

#### background

```js
      const timer = setInterval(
        fetchAndUpdateMaterial({ materialId, commit, timer }),
        delay,
      );
```

and the param `timer` is marked by `eslint`: `'timer' was used before it was defined`.

so I think it's not the right or elegant way to use `setInterval`.

#### target

no `eslint error` without using `setTimeout` recursively

(I'm not a native speaker, so thanks to read the problem)

Comment: `fetchAndUpdateMaterial({ materialId, commit, timer })` -> `() => fetchAndUpdateMaterial({ materialId, commit, timer })`? Or does `fetchAndUpdateMaterial` return a function? In the latter case, you *cannot* pass the `timer` variable before it's defined, so ESLint is correct.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks! the problem solved! I forgot to change the definition of `fetchAndUpdateMaterial `